# Where to store a file to be included in a custom template?

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I want to add a form to a WordPress site. After reading [this](http://www.blogmarketingacademy.com/how-to-custom-page-template-wordpress/), I got the idea of it.

The site uses [tempera theme](http://www.cryoutcreations.eu/tempera/).

In folder `tempera/templates` I recreated a template as template for the custom page.

Now I want to `include("form.php")`.

Where should i store `form.php`? In `tempera/includes`  or in the folder of the installation?

Would `include("form.php")` work or I would have to go up directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the file wherever you'd like in your theme. You should use whatever organization scheme makes sense to you. I wouldn't put it in the theme root because, if you have a lot of partials, it will get cluttered quickly.

If you have several forms you could create a `forms` directory within your theme. You could then use [`get_template_part`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) to include it.

```
get_template_part('forms/my-form');
```

The above example assumes your form is stored in `theme/forms/my-form.php`.

Comment: thanks, i have 1 form eventually it might grow to a few, so  you're saying that with 1 form i should `include('../../../../form.php')` or `include(_dir_(_dir_(_file_))).form.php`

Comment: I recommend using `get_template_part` instead of `include`. That way you can just specify an absolute path within your theme without worrying about its path relative to the current file. If the form were in your theme root, you would just call `get_template_part('form')` to include it.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help! where would i edit, this is the [templete page](http://paste.ofcode.org/tRYBeJzTBAzbGfFmy3dZq6) is it <?php the_content(); */?> & <?php the_title(); ?>

Comment: If you want the form the replace the content, you could just replace the loop with the form: http://paste.ofcode.org/HtKBkrhPjgedgazfNbEMiX

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*' in /home/html/wp-content/themes/tempera/templates/template-form.php on line 17   this is on line 17 <?php the_content(); */?>

Comment: It looks like you have the trailing portion of a comment but not the opening. Remove the `*/` after `the_content();`

Answer (score -3):

you have to put this file inside your theme folder. As per your referred tutorial it has created a custom page template. As you create you template and place it in you active theme. in the admin panel template option will start showing you custom template.

Comment: Why to put in theme folder? reasons? benefits? Please do not post such answer you will count down as number of downvotes.

Comment: @KeepCoding Could you please update my answer? where custom page templates need  to place in word press ?

Comment: Well, certainly I cant sorry. I was meant to say one line answers are discouraged in SO and as per the manners of posting answer group members do not take it good so please improve your answer as per the rules of SO and add more information to question. I was not meant to discouraged you please and sorry if you feels so. @manish..